# How to trigger notifications in Android?

Tags: android

I am building an Android app with a server at back end. What I want to do is, whenever anything new is updated in server the app should trigger a notification into the users phone showing the newly added content.

Comment: ... Google Cloud Messaging for Android ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITED TO ADD: This is even more important as of Android M and beyond. As part of a comprehensive effort to improve battery life, the OS actively restricts many of the techniques that apps have used in the past for sync and notifications. Use built-in methods like JobScheduler and GCM in order to avoid issues.

The core notification mechanism in Android is Google Cloud Messaging (GCM), documented [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html). It's built in to the platform at a low level and directly supported by mobile networks, so it's usually the most efficient choice. It doesn't have a guaranteed latency, so it may not be appropriate for very time-sensitive messages, but it's generally quite fast--at least as fast as sending SMS, for instance.

There are a number of different commercial products as well as FOSS libraries that wrap GCM in various ways, for instance to provide support for very old (pre-Froyo) devices or devices without Google enabled, or to provide a single cross-platform solution between various competing mobile platforms. Firebase, Parse, and Urban Airship are some that I'm aware of.

To use GCM, you need to get an API key from Google. You use this API key to authenticate requests to the GCM server. Once you have a key, sending a notification is as easy as sending a POST request to the GCM server. GCM also supports XMPP, but I haven't used it.

On the client side, your app needs to call the GCM API to register for messages. You provide the project name that you used to create the API key, so that GCM knows which server messages should go to your client app. Once your app has registered, incoming messages will be sent to it as intents, which you can receive by implementing a BroadcastReceiver.

There's a [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html) on the Android developer site that walks you through the GCM process.

Comment: Isn't it possible to set a time limit, after which the app automatically checks the server for any updated content and shows the notification.  If yes then how to do it. Please help.

Comment: Yes, that is possible, although unless your server is updated frequently, it will be far less efficient than the GCM solution. Use AlarmManager.setInexactRepeating() to set an alarm that wakes your app periodically. Or on Lollipop or above, use JobScheduler, which gives you more options (wake only if a data connection is available, for instance, so you don't waste battery trying to contact an unreachable server).